# XSL Remove preceding sibling based on Element value

Tags: xslt

Hi I require help parsing the following XML.

```
<xmeml>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>abc</Unit>
        <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Unit>bcd</Unit>
        <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
    </Test>
</Doc>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>abc</Unit>
        <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Unit>cde</Unit>
        <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
    </Test> 
</Doc>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>abc</Unit>
        <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Unit>def</Unit>
        <Unit2>4567</Unit2>
    </Test> 
</Doc>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>abc</Unit>
        <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Unit>efg</Unit>
        <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
    </Test> 
</Doc>
</xmeml>
```

ending up with the following

```
<xmeml>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>bcd</Unit>
        <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
    </Test>
</Doc>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>abc</Unit>
        <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Unit>cde</Unit>
        <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
    </Test> 
</Doc>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>def</Unit>
        <Unit2>4567</Unit2>
    </Test> 
</Doc>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>abc</Unit>
        <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Unit>efg</Unit>
        <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
    </Test> 
</Doc>
</xmeml>
```

I am attempting to create a XSLT doc to do this but as yet have not found one that works.
I should note that the required matching parameters within  are , in this case "abc", are variables and will never be a static searchable entity.

So in english my XSL would be like this:
For any parent containing a matching 'Unit' value 
 delete all preceding parents 'Test' containing a duplicate value within 'Unit' except the last.

All help most appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean, delete all `<Test>` elements whose `<Unit>` value matches that of a succeeding `<Test>` element?

Comment: No Sorry, Delete all previous <Test> elements whose <Unit> value matches that of a preceding <Unit> element. I think we are saying the same thing.

Comment: FYI, your sample document is not well-formed: Instead of `</Unit2>`, it's always `<Unit2>`.

Comment: I've added an answer that shows how to do what I think you want to do. Please add some additional (counter-)examples if that's not sufficient or let me know if you need any further explanations.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: When doing so, one needs to be very careful about not selecting too much, though. As always in SO questions, I assume the above to be a minimized example, so unless that's explicitly ruled out, there may actually well be other `<Unit>` elements in the document besides those with the `/xmeml/Doc/Test/Unit` path explicitly asked for.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: The OP doesn't mention the element name `Doc` in his requirements. Also, except in a minimized example, efficiency matters and the Muenchian grouping method is many factors of magnitude faster (sublinear, often O(1))) than the quadratic (O(N^2)) grouping method that searches for matches scanninf the whole document.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: The OP shows `<Doc>` in the input Xml and doesn't state that any `Test/Unit` subtrees outside of `<Doc>` elements should be deleted as well.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, My answer now only treats such `Test` elements. It doesn't reference any `Doc` element as this is unnecessary. And, of course, it is using the most efficient known XSLT 1.0 grouping method.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, The OP's example *happens* not to have any other parent for `Test` than `Doc`. This doesn't make it necessary to hardcode the name `Doc` and to depend on it.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: That may create unwanted side-effects. As long as the OP doesn't state that particular parts of the sample source code may be subject to variation, I generally consider it good programming practice to restrict as far as possible and thereby avoid undesired side-effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the identity template to copy the whole document and override that template with an empty template for elements that you want to delete. For checking whether a `<Test>` element should be deleted, you can compare its `<Unit>` value to that of following siblings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/xmeml/Doc/Test[(Unit = following-sibling::Test/Unit) or (Unit = ../following-sibling::Doc/Test/Unit)][descendant::Unit2[starts-with(.,'1234')]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As there are two possibilities of how those following `<Unit>` values can occur, both conditions are explicitly written and joined with the `or` operator in the condition.

The two possibilities along with their respective XPath conditions are:

- in a succeeding `<Test>` element in the same parent element as the current one:
  `Unit = following-sibling::Test/Unit`
- in a `<Test>` element in a succeeding `<Doc>` sibling of the current `<Doc>` element:
  `Unit = ../following-sibling::Doc/Test/Unit`

Assuming this input:

```
<xmeml>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>abc</Unit>
        <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Unit>bcd</Unit>
        <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
    </Test>
</Doc>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>abc</Unit>
        <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Unit>cde</Unit>
        <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
    </Test> 
</Doc>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>abc</Unit>
        <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Unit>def</Unit>
        <Unit2>4567</Unit2>
    </Test> 
</Doc>
<Doc>
    <Test>
        <Unit>abc</Unit>
        <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Unit>efg</Unit>
        <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
    </Test> 
</Doc>
</xmeml>
```

The XSLT creates this output:

```
<xmeml>
  <Doc>
    <Test>
      <Unit>bcd</Unit>
      <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
    </Test>
  </Doc>
  <Doc>
    <Test>
      <Unit>abc</Unit>
      <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
    </Test>
    <Test>
      <Unit>cde</Unit>
      <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
    </Test>
  </Doc>
  <Doc>
    <Test>
      <Unit>def</Unit>
      <Unit2>4567</Unit2>
    </Test>
  </Doc>
  <Doc>
    <Test>
      <Unit>abc</Unit>
      <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
    </Test>
    <Test>
      <Unit>efg</Unit>
      <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
    </Test>
  </Doc>
</xmeml>
```

Comment: Thanks O.R. Mapper, Ive found there are some extra complications in the structure of the document. Ive updated the original post to reflect the trickier structure.

Comment: @user1540142: I have updated my answer to deal with the additional complications.

Comment: You Nailed IT !! Can I ask one last favour though? What iF I wanted to do the same but include an AND Test[decendant::Unit2[(starts-with(.,'1234'))]] to the string.

Comment: @user1540142: You can have several `[]` restrictions for a given node in an XPath expression. All of them have to be satisfied for the node to be selected. Hence, just add your `[]` restriction after the one that is already there (omit `Test` there). i.e. `/xmeml/Doc/Test[(Unit = following-sibling::Test/Unit) or (Unit = ../following-sibling::Doc/Test/Unit)][decendant::Unit2[starts-with(.,'1234')]]`

Comment: Thank You O R Mapper. Ill play with this for a day. Your help has been invaluable.

Comment: Hi O R Mapper, I've been playing with the [][] method and they seem to produce the same results as []. ill update the example. Thanks.

Comment: the difference in the template match is that I require something like  template match = "/xmeml/Doc/Test[(Unit = following-sibling::Test/Unit) or (Unit = ../following-sibling::Doc/Test/Unit)]  [/xmeml/Doc/Test[(Unit2 = following-sibling::Test/Unit2) or (Unit2 = ../following-sibling::Doc/Test/Unit2)]

Comment: IE : both Unit and Unit2 are not pre-known elements. Before it was working because we knew the Unit2 element to be 1234. unfortunately we don't now :(

Comment: @user1540142: I have updated my answer to show the two conditions. Is it possible that you didn't get a new result because you and I had originally written `decendant` instead of `descendant`, so the XSLT wasn't successfully executed due to the typo?

Comment: @user1540142: I am not sure what you want to express by *not pre-known*; is this already solved by the updated answer?

Comment: Hi O R Mapper. Dimitre recommended I start a new question because I kept changing the Goal Posts. So my apologies for possibly confusing the issue. Your prior answers helped me solve a few of my other problems so you are AWESOME. Lets say SOLVED :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways of performing grouping in XSLT 1.0 -- simple, using a `preceding::` or `following::` axis, and, the more efficient Muenchian grouping method -- using keys.

**Here is the more efficient, Muenchian method:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:key name="kParentByUnit" match="Test[Unit]" use="Unit"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="Test[Unit]">
       <xsl:if test=
       "generate-id()
       =
        generate-id(key('kParentByUnit', Unit)[position()=last()])">

        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
       </xsl:if>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<xmeml>
    <Doc>
        <Test>
            <Unit>abc</Unit>
            <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
        </Test>
        <Test>
            <Unit>bcd</Unit>
            <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
        </Test>
    </Doc>
    <Doc>
        <Test>
            <Unit>abc</Unit>
            <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
        </Test>
        <Test>
            <Unit>cde</Unit>
            <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
        </Test>
    </Doc>
    <Doc>
        <Test>
            <Unit>abc</Unit>
            <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
        </Test>
        <Test>
            <Unit>def</Unit>
            <Unit2>4567</Unit2>
        </Test>
    </Doc>
    <Doc>
        <Test>
            <Unit>abc</Unit>
            <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
        </Test>
        <Test>
            <Unit>efg</Unit>
            <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
        </Test>
    </Doc>
</xmeml>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<xmeml>
   <Doc>
      <Test>
         <Unit>bcd</Unit>
         <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
      </Test>
   </Doc>
   <Doc>
      <Test>
         <Unit>cde</Unit>
         <Unit2>3456</Unit2>
      </Test>
   </Doc>
   <Doc>
      <Test>
         <Unit>def</Unit>
         <Unit2>4567</Unit2>
      </Test>
   </Doc>
   <Doc>
      <Test>
         <Unit>abc</Unit>
         <Unit2>1234</Unit2>
      </Test>
      <Test>
         <Unit>efg</Unit>
         <Unit2>2345</Unit2>
      </Test>
   </Doc>
</xmeml>
```

Comment: I have updated the example and have also been trying to use your code but it is only deleting the first occurrence. Can it delete everything except the last occurrence ?

Comment: @user1540142: I updated this answer and it produces what I think you want as correct result -- not what you specified literally, but what you described as requirement -- there is only one `"abc" present in the result.

Comment: @user1540142: Seems your desired output contains two different `<Unit>abc</Unit>` . Is this a mistake? If so, please edit the question and correct

Comment: Hi Dimitre, I now require a match for any Test elements containing both duplicates of Unit and Unit2 .So the example is the required output.

Comment: @user1540142: You haven't described this in the question. Also, it is much better to start a *new* question -- not to delete the old one -- these are in fact two different questions. People hate spending 3+ days to provide several answers to the same question, because its poster changed his mind continually. Please, ask a new question and I'll answer it tomorrow, after waking up.